# Balance variable keeps resetting after each loop

Tags: debugging, variables, python-3.6

I was wondering how I'm supposed to get my "balance" variable to change depending on the value added or subtracted to it each time, without resetting for the next loop.
At the moment it will add or subtract a given value and return the correct number but on the next loop it will use the original base value instead of using the new value from the previous loop.

```
import time 

print ("Welcome to balance tracker!")
sBal=float(input ("Starting balance:    "))
float(sBal)
transactionAmounts = []
transactionTypes = []
print ("Your current balance is", '$',sBal)
while True:
    input("Press enter to continue")
    print ("""
         ------------
         [A]ddition
         [S]ubtraction
         [H]istory
         [I]nformation
         [Q]uit
            ------------
          """)

    choice=input("What would you like to do?    ")
    choice = choice.upper()

    if choice == "A":
        aval=float(input ("Enter amount you would like to add here:    "))
        nBal=(sBal)+(aval)
        transactionTypes.append('Addition')
        transactionAmounts.append(float(aval))
        balance = float(sBal) + aval
        print ("Your current balance is $",balance) 
    elif choice == "S":
        aval=input("Enter amount you would like to subtract here:    ")
        nBal=float(sBal)-float(aval)
        transactionTypes.append('Subtraction')
        transactionAmounts.append (float(aval))
        balance = float(sBal) - aval
        print ("Your current balance is $",balance) 

    elif choice == "H":
        aCount = 1
        tCount = 0
        for i in transactionAmounts:
            print ('Transaction',aCount,':',transactionTypes[tCount],i)
            aCount = aCount + 1
            tCount = tCount + 1


    elif choice == "Q":
        break

    else:
        print ("invalid choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is that when your assigning your balance variable, your adding sBal(starting balance) every time to the amount they would like to add... This is causing the balance to always be set back to the starting balance plus or minus the amount added. Try defining sBal as balance also like so...

```
balance = float(input("Starting balance:      ")) #line 5
float(sBal) #<<<can be deleted #line 6
```

Also don't forget to alter anywhere in the code that calls sBal to call balance.

```
print("Your current balance is ", "$", difference) #line 9

balance = float(balance) (+ or -) aval #lines 30 and 37
```

Also you can delete your nBal(new balance) as it is never called.